# Android: WifiInfo.getIpAddress() deprecated

Tags: android, android-wifi

API 31 deprecated getIpAddress() Need help getting the address from the callback implementation

```
val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {}


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(network: Network, networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities) {
        super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)
        val wifiInfo = networkCapabilities.transportInfo as? WifiInfo
    }

    override fun onLinkPropertiesChanged(network: Network, linkProperties: LinkProperties) {
        super.onLinkPropertiesChanged(network, linkProperties)
        // val ipV4Address = ?

    }
};
```

Answer (score 9):

for deprecated method you can read official android Documents,
as document syas :

> This method was deprecated in API level 31. Use the methods on LinkProperties which can be obtained either via NetworkCallback#onLinkPropertiesChanged(Network, LinkProperties) or ConnectivityManager#getLinkProperties(Network).

so by this method that i have added here you can obtain all of ip address:

```
   private fun getIpAddress() {
    val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
     if (connectivityManager is ConnectivityManager) {
        var link:LinkProperties =  connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.activeNetwork) as LinkProperties
         Log.e("Network", link.linkAddresses.toString())
    }

}
```

***Notice:*** link.linkAddresses method may return array of addresses

Comment: It WOOORKS!! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For getting ip address (like `192.168.1.123`) on Wifi network:

```
fun Context.getConnectivityManager() = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

fun getIpAddress(context: Context) = with(context.getConnectivityManager()) {
    getLinkProperties(activeNetwork)!!.linkAddresses[1].address.hostAddress!!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using this solution, I'm wondering to access linkAddresses[1] , linkAddresses size should be 2 or more. Will there be any cases where link addresses size is less than 2 (need to handle this scenario)? . I could not find any documentation on the linkAddresses size and order in which values are passed.

Comment: @Rachita Nanda Not sure about that either, the only thing I can find is this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LinkProperties#getLinkAddresses().

Answer (score 3):

You should now get the ip address via [ConnectivityManager.getLinkProperties()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getLinkProperties(android.net.Network)) function if you don't want to use the callback approach. According to docs in the link this function is available since API 21 (Android 5), so you can replace your current approach of getting ip address with a the suggested one if your minSDK is >= 21:

```
val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

val linkAddresses = connectivityManager?.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)?.linkAddresses

val ipV4Address = linkAddresses?.firstOrNull { linkAddress ->
                linkAddress.address.hostAddress?.contains('.') ?: false }?.address?.hostAddress
```

You need to filter returned results because there will be multiple ipV6 addresses and only one ipV4 address. Here is what is returned from `linkAddresses` without filtering:
[image]

This is why one of other answers here isn't fully correct as nobody guarantees that the ipV4 address will be under index 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
private fun getDeviceIpAddress(): String? {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        val ipAddressInt = wifiManager.connectionInfo.ipAddress
        val ipAddress: String? = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ipAddressInt)
        if (ipAddress.isNullOrBlank() || ipAddress.isEmpty()) {
            return String.format(
                "%d.%d.%d.%d", ipAddressInt and 0xff, ipAddressInt shr 8 and 0xff,
                ipAddressInt shr 16 and 0xff, ipAddressInt shr 24 and 0xff
            )
        }
    } else {
        val linkProperties =
            connManager.getLinkProperties(connManager.activeNetwork)
        linkProperties?.let { linkProp ->
            for (linkAddress in linkProp.linkAddresses) {
                val inetAddress = linkAddress.address
                if (inetAddress is Inet4Address
                    && !inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()
                    && inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()
                ) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java code:

```
public static Optional<String> getIPv4Address(Context context) {
    var connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager instanceof ConnectivityManager cm) {
        LinkProperties link = cm.getLinkProperties(cm.getActiveNetwork());

        Log.e("IPAddress List", link.getLinkAddresses().toString()); 
        
        // return only one IPv4Address
        return link.getLinkAddresses().stream()
                .filter(linkAddress -> linkAddress.getAddress().getAddress().length == 4)
                .findFirst()
                .map(LinkAddress::toString);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please revise your answer with an explanation on why you code solves the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer